# Trigger a fade when swapping between classes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fade

I have following code working so far:  [**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/4um7eypw/)

The relevant JS is here:

```
// Define classes & background element.
var classes = ['bg1','bg2','bg3','bg4'],
    $bg = document.getElementById('blah');
// On first run:
$bg.className = sessionStorage.getItem('currentClass') || classes[0];
// On button click:
$('.swapper').mousedown(function () {
  // (1) Get current class of background element,
  // find its index in "classes" Array.
  var currentClassIndex = classes.indexOf($bg.className);
  // (2) Get new class from list.
  var nextClass = classes[(currentClassIndex + 1)%classes.length];
  // (3) Assign new class to background element.
  $bg.className = nextClass;
  // (4) Save new class in sessionStorage.
  sessionStorage.setItem('currentClass', nextClass);
});
```

For my purposes, this functionally working great -- I can click a single button to continually swap between those four classes while also storing the current class to sessionStorage, so that when I click links on my website, the `currentClass` is loaded right away.  (**Note**:  on my website the setup is the same, but the classes `bg1`, `bg2`, `bg3`, and `bg4` contain background images.)

**What I'd like it to do:**
When swapping from one class to another, I'd like it to do a quick/short cross-fade.  Right now it just snaps from one class/background to another.

My thinking was:  is there a way I can trigger a CSS class transition or animation that contains the fade, perhaps as a parent class?  I know there's a jQuery `fade` function, but I haven't been able to get it working with my setup so that it triggers on mouseClick.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r8rq2t6z/1/?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks for the response!  The issue with your example is that it does not work when the class contains a background image, for whatever reason.  **[See jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/tb3yht5v/)**

Comment: Background images are not supported, only color is

Comment: @ArunPJohny [So I sort of have it working here](https://jsfiddle.net/zym600ja/1/), but the image is swapping just before the `fadeOut` occurs.  What am I doing wrong?  Also ideally I would like the images to fade from one to the other... right now it fades to white, and then the other image fades in.  Maybe I need to layer the classes/images and re-order their z-index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an updated [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zym600ja/2/) based on your comment where you said you've sort of having it work.

I've added the timeout functions

```
setTimeout(function(){$bg.className = nextClass}, 500);
setTimeout(function(){$($bg).fadeIn(500)}, 500)
```

The first timeout makes it so that the image is swapped right *after* the first image fades out. The second timeout gives it a bit of time to load in so it's not so jittery.

You can play with the `}, 500);` number to get it timed just like you want, `500` is half a second, `1000` is a second etc.

Comment: This is wonderful, thanks so much!  I've got it working with your method.  The only other thing I might mess with is that between page loads (i.e. if I click a link on my site) if the class _is not_ `bg1` there's a slight flicker.  Reason being, `bg1` is quickly loaded at first (it's the one defined in the HTML) but then the sessionStorage loads in the correct background.  I've partially remedied this by giving each `bg#` class a fadein style in CSS.  It most fixes it, but it's not perfect. Maybe I'd have to use a dummy class that contains no background and then swap the correct one in on load

Comment: Glad I could help, as for your newest problem, I think the most elegant solution is the dummy class with no background, or a gray background where you can fade in the correct image on $( document ).ready()

Comment: Actually you got me thinking... at first I was going to swap the dummy class for another on load using jQuery, but instead I swapped `bg1` in the HTML with `bgTemp` and just made the `bgTemp` class pure white.   I think what's happening now on load is it swaps `bgTemp` for whatever was stored in the session.  This works since instead of displaying `bg1` for a split second, it'll now just show a pure white background instead from `bgTemp`.  Thanks again Amir!